# Method with generic element List and access to field by reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have a compound problem. I want to write a method that receives 3 arguments:

- A string to compare
- A List of generic element type
- A field name (of List element) to compare its value to the first argument

This is what I have so far, but it is incomplete, since I don't know how to define the second argument and I don't know how to get the List elements class to define a single element (see the "?????" in the code below)

```
public class Object1 {
    String name;
    ...
}

public class Object2 {
    String address;
    ...
}

public class MyClass {
    ...
    private List<Object1> list1 = new ArrayList<Object1>();
    private List<Object2> list2 = new ArrayList<Object2>();
    ...
    private boolean isUnique(String s, List<?> list, String field) {
        boolean result = true;

        ?????? element = null;
        Field f = null;
        Class<?> c = ?????.class;
        try {
            f = c.getDeclaredField(field);
            f.setAccessible(true);
        } catch( NoSuchFieldException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int size = list.size();
        for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
            element = list.get(i);
            try {
                if( s.equals(f.get(element))) {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            } catch( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch( IllegalAccessException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public boolean check(){
        boolean result = isUnique("Stewart", list1, "name");
        result = result & isUnique("21 pine", list2, "address");
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Object element = null;
    Field f = null;
    if(list.size()>0)
    {
      Class<?> c = list.get(0).getClass();
      try {
        f = c.getDeclaredField(field);
        f.setAccessible(true);
    } catch( NoSuchFieldException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int size = list.size();
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        element = list.get(i);
        try {
            if( s.equals(f.get(element))) {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        } catch( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch( IllegalAccessException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return result;
}else
{
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Some clarification: Is then `List<?> list` the right way to declare the list argument?